# please help to explain the output of this c program

Tags: c

After executing i am getting the output as 12 6 11. please explain how this is possible

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAN(x,y) (x)>(y)?(x):(y)
int main()
{
    int i = 10,j = 5,k = 0;
    k = MAN(i++,++j);
    printf("%d %d %d", i, j, k);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ask to your friend https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770563/c-macros-and-variable.

Comment: Do what the preprocessor does: replace the macro with its definition, write i++ on every occurence of x and ++j for y. You'll see quickly then...

Answer (score 1):

The macro will expand the line
`k=MAN(i++,j++)`
as
`k=(i++)>(j++)?(i++):(j++);`
`k=(i++)>(j++)?(i++)`, `(j++)` will not be evaluated.

so 
i will be incremented twice and result in `12` j will be incremented once so `6` when k will be assigned `i` value is `11 so its value as`11`.